# What's the easiest way to get Dictionary functionality in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, dictionary, string

I want to statically define a mapped array of strings like:

```
var dict = {cat:50, bat:10, rat:30};
```

and lookup values within it like:

```
MessageBox.Show( dict["cat"] )
```

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.NET?  Your code example shows C#, but your tags show VB.NET.

Comment: That's actually JavaScript :) but I want to do something like that in VB.NET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()

With dict 
    .Add("Cat", 50)
    .Add("Bat", 10)
    .Add("Rat", 30)
End With
```

Comment: `As New Dictionary`? or has VB changed since last I used?

Comment: Is this the only way? Doesn't VB have built-in support for keyed arrays?

Comment: @dotjoe,Kyle,smoore: it is just the short way of doing:
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
which is a shorthand version of:
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
dict = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()

It is possible to use the shortest version due to this scenario being a "special" case: the variable is assigned with a value immediately upon decleration, the assigned value is newly created, and the variable's type is identical to the value's type.

Comment: cool SO now recognizes the @username comment replies in your recent responses. lol at Hanin...I think you missed the part where `New` was missing from the answer.

Comment: @dotjoe, I sure did! Thought you guys are new to the New keyword :-)

Answer (score 5):

In .NET 4.0:

```
Dim d As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From
    {{"cat", 50}, {"bat", 10}, {"rat",30 }}
```

Comment: This is supposed to be the preferred way of doing Collection Initialization now

Comment: VB.NET reports "Array initializers are only valid for arrays".. Have you actually tested this code?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if this code is specific to .NET 4.0.  The syntax is slightly different there.

Comment: Whup.  This is speculative syntax, see here:  http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2008/05/05/23212.aspx.  It does exist in .NET 4.0, however (under slightly different syntax).  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617(VS.100).aspx